# Data Processing Inequality under Noise

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, independence, information-theory, noise

Consider three random variables $X, Y, Z$ satisfying $X \perp Z \mid Y$.
By the data processing inequality: $I(X;Z) \leq I(X;Y)$.

Now, consider the alternative setting where $Y_\epsilon = Y + \epsilon_1$ and $Z_\epsilon = Z + \epsilon_2$ for independent zero-mean noise variables $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$.
Denote by $\mathcal{Y}_\epsilon$ a set of independent "copies" of $Y_\epsilon$ and assume that $\mathrm{Var}[Y \mid \mathcal{Y}_\epsilon] \leq \tau$ for some arbitrarily small $\tau > 0$.

In general, we have that $X \not\perp Z_\epsilon \mid \mathcal{Y}_\epsilon$.
However, intuitively, the conditional independence should still hold "approximately", and the "information gain" about $X$ of the noisy $Z_\epsilon$ should be small.
Is it possible to give a bound of $I(X;Z_\epsilon)$ in terms of $I(X;\mathcal{Y}_\epsilon)$ similar to the data processing inequality?

Answer (score 1):

We have (in general)
$$I(X;Y) - I(X;Z) = H(X|Z) -H(X|Y) \ge H(X|Y,Z)-H(X|Y)$$

But here, in the original setting, we have $ H(X|Y,Z)=H(X|Y)$, from which the inequality follows.

Let introduce now $A=\mathcal{Y}_\epsilon$, $B=Z_e$

Let $\alpha = H(Y|A)=H(Y)+H(A|Y)-H(A)$ and $\beta = H(Z|B)= H(Z)+H(B|Z)-H(B)$

We expect these numbers to be small.

Also, let define $  \alpha' = \alpha - H(Y|X,A) \le \alpha$ and
$ \beta' = \beta - H(Z|X,B) \le \beta$

Now
$$
\begin{align}
I(X;A)-I(X;B) &= H(X|B)-H(X|A)\\
  &=H( X| Z, B) + H(Z|B) - H(Z| X, B) - [H(X |Y,A) + H(Y|A) - H(Y|X,A) ] \\
  &=H(X |Z) - H(X|Y)  + \beta' - \alpha'\\
  &=I(X;Y) - I(X;Z) + \beta' - \alpha' \\
  & \ge \beta' - \alpha'
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That's super cool! However, I am wondering why is $\alpha' \leq \alpha$ and $\beta' \leq \beta$? This will not hold when the random variables are continuous, right?

Comment: Is it also possible to get a bound like this when the random variables are continuous?

Comment: $\alpha' \leq \alpha$ is also valid for differential entropies (because $H(Y|X)\le H(Y)$ is also valid in the continuous) . What is not valid is $\alpha'>0$, but that's not relevant, I'm deleting that.

Comment: I think the lower bound of $0$ works due to monotonicity of MI: $\alpha' = I(Y; X, A) - I(Y; A) \geq 0$

Comment: I am thinking that it might be a bit more complicated. Consider, for example, the case where $X$ is Gaussian and $Y = X$. Then, $I(X; Y) = \infty$ and $(|,) = -\infty$. So if we directly apply the data processing inequality in the last step, then we only get the trivial lower bound of $-\infty$.